# Smallest sphere containing three tetrahedra?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, euclidean-geometry, packing-and-covering

What is the smallest possible radius of a sphere which contains 3 identical plastic tetrahedra with side length 1?

Comment: I don't understand this question. Is there some condition on the location of the tetraherdra?

Comment: Presumably the OP meant: three unit regular tetrahedra with disjoint interiors.

Comment: What is the significance of the word, "plastic"? Does it mean you can change the shape of each tetrahedron at will?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I think it might just mean “solid” in this context.

Comment: I think it means the OP is playing with plastic tetrahedra. Possibly dice, some games have used them, although they don't roll well.

Comment: Plastic = reference to plastic number? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_number

Answer (score 11):

Unclear this is best, but: $r=\sqrt{3}/2$.

[image: ThreeTetra]

---

JukkaKohonen's suggestion:

[image: JK]

I made no attempt to optimize, but this certainly shows
the smallest sphere has radius strictly less than $\sqrt{3}/2$.

Comment: Hmmm, this is nonunique. You can pivot the tetrahedra about the triply shared edge.

Comment: @OscarLanzi: Yes, you are right.

Comment: It seems you could slide the rightmost tetrahedron down and left, along the face that it shares with its neighbor, and the radius would decrease.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen Try simultaneously pivoting the central tetrahedron about the triply shared edge of the current figure as well as sliding the left one.